# Compare dataframe value with value of another dataframe value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Okay so I have two data frames

Dataframe a

```
   name  LAT   LONG
0  AAA   XX.XX XX.XX
1  BBB   XX.XX XX.XX
2  CCC   XX.XX XX.XX
3  DDD   XX.XX XX.XX
```

Dataframe b

```
     name  LAT   LONG
0  EEE   XX.XX XX.XX
1  FFF   XX.XX XX.XX
2  GGG   XX.XX XX.XX
3  HHH   XX.XX XX.XX
```

Now i want to create a new dataframe containing all the points from dataframe a where the distance between the point from data frame a is less than X meters from the point in dataframe b.

I have used nested for loops to achieve this but it takes too much time. I have used the formula
geopy.distance.distance(coords_1, coords_2).meters
to calculate the distance.

Any suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: don't think you can get any better than double for loops, since you need to compare each point with each point from the second list. You could use some clustering, but that will take quite some time to implement.

Comment: What is the projection of your lat/long? Please replace your XX.XX by real values to be reproducible.

Comment: As @corralien said, kindly provide actual values, with expected output dataframe

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with either geopy or working with LAT/LONG but if I had two coordinates and wanted the points from a df that is close enough to a point in another df I'd do something like this

```
data1 = [['aaa', 1, 2], ['bbb', 3, 5]] 
data2 = [['ccc', 1, 8], ['ddd', 3, 9]]
columns_names = ['name', 'LAT', 'LONG'] 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns=column_names) 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns=column_names)

distance_of_interest = 6      # or 1 in your case

df3 = pd.DataFrame(df1[np.sqrt((df1.LAT-df2.LAT)**2 + (df1.LONG - df2.LONG)**2) < distance_of_interest],
                   columns=column_names) 


df3 >
        name  LAT  LONG
     1  bbb    3     5
```

Although this assumes point `aaa` corresponds to `ccc` etc. If you want to compare `aaa` to both `ccc` and `ddd` I can't come up with a quick answer that doesn't use for loops.

Hope it helps you solve it some way, good luck.

Comment: Interesting approach but point I want to compare aaa to both ccc and ddd.

Comment: @AbhinavParab then I'm pretty sure you wont get out of using for loops, whether you write them or not at some point there will be for loops!


E: My solution is also using for loops, for clarity. It is just not me who wrote them.